# UIControl.State.Highlighted image on UIButton only works after first touch event

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a set of buttons I'd like to have crossfade through a different highlighted image than normal when touched.  The technique below works fine, but only after the second touch event on the same button.  The first touch produces the standard "faded dark grey" on the whole button; from then on future touches it crossfades correctly through the pictures on highlight.

I've only tested this in the simulator, is that he issue?  If not, how do I produce the correct highlighted state on every touch?  Thanks!

```
@IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!       
@IBAction func someButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "My Image.png"), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
    }, completion: nil)

//...other functions

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the button's highlighted image initially at the time of setting up `UIButton` properties or in `viewDidLoad()` by writing the code below.

```
yourButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "My Image.png"), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
```

**Reason for not working your code**

The button action `@IBAction func someButton(_ sender: UIButton)` always call only on release of the user's finger so by this time UIButton doesn't has the image for the highlighted state for the first time. Later on, the image is set through animation so it is animating perfectly.

**Edit**

You can make transition of `UIButton` with firebase call or some other event action by creating a separate function like shown below. Use the `UIButton`'s `outlet` to access the button.

```
@IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!

func buttonTransition() {

    UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        someButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "My Image.png"), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

So, you can call `buttonTransition()` function from wherever you want.

Comment: Is there a way to call this from outside the button itself?  I'd like to be able to run the transition from either the button press or a Firebase call.  I keep getting `Cannot convert value of type '/**Some type*/' to expected argument type 'UIView'` when I try any other `with:` item.

Comment: I've edited the answer @moosgrn. Please have a look at **Edit** to clarify your doubt. If any issues are still there, feel free to comment here..!! 

Answer (score 0):

It is working on the second click because you have written the transition code inside the button click action. Just write that code in the viewDidLoad or viewWillApear and it will work before the first click and will set the transition on the button. Write something like this in viewDidLoad:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "image.png"), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

here button is the outlet variable of the button created in storyboard.